# unsigned to integer conversion VHDL

Tags: integer, vhdl

I'm trying to convert an `unsigned(7 downto 0)` data to an integer!

I have this

```
SIGNAL SQ_X1: INTEGER RANGE 0 TO 1024:= conv_integer(pos_ini_x);
```

where `pos_ini_x` comes from another module that is the result of a random number calculation. Syntax issues are good but when I convert to assign to `SQ_X1` variable, it doesn't work well, it always provide a zero as a result.

If you know how to improve this conversion and resolve this problem and explain why it happens, could you help me please?

It would be appreciated.

Comment: Why is your integer's range from 0 to 1024? I assume your integer should use 10 bits, but this requires 11.

Comment: Because it is the length of a monitor. The pos_ini_x variable is defined:

pos_ini_x: IN    UNSIGNED(15 downto 0) ;

and the integer:

SIGNAL SQ_X1: INTEGER RANGE 0 TO 1024:= conv_integer(pos_ini_x);

but as Kevin said, Im trying to initialize the signal.

Comment: Which monitor has a resolution of 1025 pixels? -- Synthesis tools won't evaluate signal initializers unless the signal is mapped to a register. And secondly synthesis tools normally require initializers be be a static expression. So the initializer can only use generics or constants for calculation, but no ports.

Comment: thanks for the observation Paebbels!
I dont initialize the SQ_X1 variable, a just did and assignment into the process before my conditional expression!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are applying `conv_integer` as an initializer to the signal. It is only called once during elaboration when `pos_ini_x` is presumably 0. If you want to update the `SQ_X1` signal after elaboration you have to use a signal assignment to change it.

Note that `conv_integer` is a nonstandard function. The standard equivalent in `ieee.numeric_std` is `to_integer`.

Comment: yes Im trying to initialize it. the module that provide this value calculated it and for now I just want to see this value.